# parsererror при отправке формы через Elementor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

При отправке форм выдает ошибку parsererror. Формы зделаны с помощью плагина Elementor Pro.  Может кто знает как решить даный вопрос?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ошибки в консоли какие?

Comment: Ошибок в консоли нет(

Comment: На вкладке network->XHR при отправке есть ошибки?

Comment: тоже нет...статус 200 везде...

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего Вы где то используете хук элементора или веб хук в форме это сообщение о том , что не получается прочесть json